# errors.add(:base) works but there is no error message present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a custom validator and add it's error message to `:base`. Basically everything is working fine but my message content is not present in `object.errors` array.

#### Validator code:

```
# app/models/video.rb

# ...

validate  :if_only_pending_video

# ...

def if_only_pending_video
  return unless job_id.present?

  if job.videos.pending.any?
    errors.add(:base, "My error message")
  end
end
```

#### Sample output:

```
FactoryGirl.build(:video).valid? # => false
FactoryGirl.build(:video).errors? # => []
```

I have about 99% test coverage and i'm sure that `valid?` returns `false` in cause of that validator. I just can't understand why there is no message present in `errors` array.

Comment: you might want to `return true unless job_id.present?` or `false`, I think returning nothing at all is not helping the validations here...

Comment: Did it solve your issue?

Comment: nope, it's still there

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the code sample is a bit incorrect by itself. At the first line you build an object and check its validness:

```
FactoryGirl.build(:video).valid? # => false
```

The result is `false` and here the mistake appears: you build a brand new `video` object and check its errors (but there are none as this object has never been validated yet):

```
FactoryGirl.build(:video).errors? # => []
# this is a completely different object.
# object_id of this video is not the same as object_id of the first one built.
```

The way you should check it is to use the same object for validation and for errors checking:

```
some_video = FactoryGirl.build(:video)
some_video.valid? # => false
some_video.errors # => [[:base, "My error message"]]
```

As a side note, you could get rid of that conditional inside of `if_only_pending_video` method and use conditional validation:

```
validate :if_only_pending_video, :if => lambda{|object| object.job_id.present? }
```